# MYSQL custom order by using FIELD function and multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `data` having 2 columns `type` & `status` as follow :

```
TYPE        STATUS

deposit     1
deposit     1
deposit     2
deposit     3
deposit     0
transfer    1
transfer    2
transfer    3
transfer    0
transfer    1
```

I need to order it by having the `status` order as (1, 2, 3 then 0) but when the `status` is `1` I need to `deposit` type to be first, then `transfer` type, and for the rest of the statuses, I only need them to be (2, 3, then 0) without paying attention to the type.

I only could figure out half of the puzzle by using this query :

```
select * from data order by FIELD(status, '1', '2', '3', '0')
```

Result :

```
TYPE        STATUS

deposit     1
transfer    1
transfer    1
deposit     1
deposit     2
transfer    2
deposit     3
deposit     3
transfer    0
deposit     0
```

The needed result is :

```
TYPE        STATUS

deposit     1
deposit     1
transfer    1
transfer    1
deposit     2
transfer    2
deposit     3
deposit     3
transfer    0
deposit     0
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to get tied into a `FIELD` expression that you would have to update if the number of status values changed, you can order by `STATUS > 0 DESC` first (which will order all positive values of `STATUS` before a `0` value), then by `STATUS` (to order positive values as 1, 2, 3 etc.), then by `TYPE` (since `deposit` is alphabetically before `transfer`):

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY STATUS > 0 DESC, STATUS, TYPE
```

Output:

```
TYPE        STATUS    
deposit     1
deposit     1
transfer    1
transfer    1
deposit     2
transfer    2
deposit     3
deposit     3
transfer    0
deposit     0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6sE38pd5zTUoGkqUErcUeH/0)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do:

```
select *
from data
order by field(status, '1', '2', '3', '0'), type
```

Comment: You mean `select * from data order by FIELD(status, '1', '2', '3', '0'), type`

Comment: Yes, this is one of the solutions. Thanks.